# Create .sql file using query results

Tags: mysql

How to store the sql query output into .sql file? I am trying to make .sql files using the result of select queries.I am using ubuntu terminal.able to save the query results in .csv format but i also want results in .sql file.

Comment: dump it with mysqldump

Comment: @Mariano MySQLDump dumps static objects only, it cannot "dump" the output of a query.

Comment: Save the query output to temporary table then dump it. Alternatively dump the structure (if needed) to .SQL file and save query output into separate .CSV file.

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1) and than dump  table2

Comment: trying the same.

Comment: `CREATE .. SELECT` without columns definition is not good idea - the table structure is not deterministic in this case. Moreover, you may obtain incorrect datatypes even. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=367d7476f88c334a16b71d7257931d79 Use full table definition (including indices, CHECK constraints and so on) in `CREATE TABLE` part, and according columns aliases in `SELECT` part.